# Cardinality of infinite words from finite alphabet is the same as that of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: cardinals, real-numbers

Let $[n]$ denote the set $\{0, 1,2, \ldots, n\}$. I want to show that $[n]^{\mathbb{N}} \simeq \mathbb{R}$. I am aware you could do this with base $n$-ary expansions of reals, but that seems a bit clunky to me. Is there a way to prove this by avoiding such expansions?

I can do this one way for $n = 1$ by enumerating the rationals, associating each real number it's "cut" of rational numbers less than it, and setting the $n$th digit of the sequence associated with $x$ to be $1$ if $r_n < x$. This gives an injection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $[1]^{\mathbb{N}}$. Can this be generalized? And what about the other direction (for Schroder Bernstein)?

Comment: Standard notation is $[n]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, so that $[0]=\emptyset$, and $[n]$ has $n$ elements.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, but I don't think that's relevant here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll  write $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}^{\mathbb N}=:W_n$ for short.

You have provided an injection $\phi:\>{\mathbb R}\to W_2$. For an injection $\psi$ in the other direction use some Cantor set construction, e.g.,
$$\psi(x):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty{2x_k\over3^k}\ .$$
On the other hand it is obvious that $W_n\subset W_m$ if $n<m$. Furthermore the sets $W_n$ and $W_{n^2}$ can be bijectively related by re-encoding: For $x\in W_n$ put $$y_k:=n x_{2k-1}+x_{2k}\qquad(k\geq1)\ .$$
Then $$\chi:\quad W_n\to W_{n^2},\qquad x\mapsto y$$
is a bijection. In this way we have shown that all $W_n$, $n\geq2$, have the same cardinality.

Comment: I like the connection between $W_n$ and $W_{n^2}$. But the reverse injection $\phi$ is really just ternary reals. Is there an alternative to that part?

Comment: Sorry I meant $\psi$ in the previous comment, not $\phi$.

Comment: You cannot prove something about ${\mathbb R}$ without using some properties of ${\mathbb R}$, e.g., the sum of a geometric series, which is needed to prove the injectivity of $\psi$. This has nothing to do with "ternary reals".

Comment: The ternary (base 3) representation of reals is what I meant in that comment, and the question really asks if there's a solution that doesn't use that. I'm sure you can prove this part without the "sum of geometric series", because everything else has been proven without using it at all.

Comment: I'm still looking for that part, but I will accept this solution.